# QueryDSL : wildcard query with query type

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

How to create a query with query types (http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e184) that use wildcard ?

Use case : For an entity called Animal i need to get all animals with at least one 'a' in the "name" property of the entity.

It should look like QAnimal.animal.name...

I use mongodb with spring data

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't something like this work

```
QAnimal.animal.name.contains("a")
```